# Java Mail Exception Error Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com is E-mail is not send

Tags: java, selenium, email, smtp

I am trying to send Emails through Gmail but exception "**Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com**".
I already **Turned on** Less secure app access and Two Step Verification should be **turned off**.

```
public class MonitoringMail
{
    public void sendMail(String mailServer, String from, String[] to, String subject, String messageBody) throws MessagingException, AddressException
    {
        boolean debug = false;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailServer); 
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        
         props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
         props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
         props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
         props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); 

        
          Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

            session.setDebug(debug);
        
        try
        {
            
            
            Transport bus = session.getTransport("smtp");
            bus.connect();
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        
         //X-Priority values are generally numbers like 1 (for highest priority), 3 (normal) and 5 (lowest).
            
             message.addHeader("X-Priority", "1");
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
             InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];
             for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
             addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType .TO, addressTo);
             message.setSubject(subject);
                  
             
             BodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();

            // body.setText(messageBody);
            body.setContent(messageBody,"text/html");

             MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
             multipart.addBodyPart(body);
            // multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
             message.setContent(multipart);
             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Sucessfully Sent mail to All Users");
             bus.close();
            
        }
        catch (MessagingException mex)
        {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

It's working earlier but one week later I got an exception.
I try to resolve this exception and I spent 3 days but I cant resolve these issues please try to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP have 2 different ports
PORTS for **SSL** 465
PORTS for **TLS/STARTTLS** 587
did you try with another ports ?

Comment: yes I try that time its give another exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with port 25.

```
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you've setup gmail account and enabled less secured apps, but Gmail account automatically turns off "allow less secured apps" option after some period of inactivity. If this code worked before,  try to check your gmail account settings again.

Answer (score -1):

In my case i  was change ports after that it's working properly